# how to configure ember-cli-babel based on environment in ember-cli-build.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, babeljs, environment

We are migrating our site to ember, so as of now we use ember as well as JSPs. Since in production, I have a polyfill loaded when my site loads, I want to use babel polyfill inside the ember app only on development and testing environment. I do not want it on production bulid. I know I can do the following

```
//ember-cli-build.js
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  'ember-cli-babel': {
    'includePolyfill': true 
  }
}
```

I need something like the following to include polyfill based on the environment.

```
//ember-cli-build.js
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  'ember-cli-babel': {
    'includePolyfill': this.ENV=='production' ? false:true 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much what you said:

In my 2.18 app,

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
       'ember-cli-babel': {
           'includePolyfill':EmberApp.env() !== 'production' 
        }
    }
}
```